# Codeigniter calendar language problem

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to get the calendar in CodeIgniter to print month names in Swedish.

In config.php I have this line:

```
$config ['language'] = 'Swedish';
```

In autoload.php I have this line:

```
$autoload ['language'] = array ('calendar');
```

In my controller:

```
$this->lang->load('calendar', 'swedish');
```

So here I am trying to print the date:

```
<? php echo date ('d M Y', $row['pubDate']);?>
```

The result is as: 23 May 2011

Month names are printed in English, which is wrong, I want it in Swedish. I have calendar_lang.php in Swedish.

Any advice on how I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter lang files are decided to "translate" only codeigniter functions, methods etc.
They do not affect default php function, like that one you are using (date).
You should look at [this page](http://atlex.nl/voorbeelden/php/datetime_localization.php) and follow the links on that page.